Unable to use react-markdown with nextjs 14.2.3
I just imported react-markdown in my app and the App crashed. Getting the following Error
./node_modules/unist-util-visit-parents/lib/index.js
Attempted import error: 'color' is not exported from 'unist-util-visit-parents/do-not-use-color' (imported as 'color').
nextjs version 14.2.3
nodejs version 21.7.2
npm    version 10.5.2
enter image description here
I installed unist-util-visit-parents but the error presist. Please let me know if you can help.
